# Is textNode always a node's firstChild?

Tags: python, xml, dom

When using the XML DOM, will the .firstChild.data method always return the contents of the node's textNode, if the node has one?

In XML file:

```
 <rtcincident>CRASH
```

Python code:

```
incidentNameInput = str(raw_input("Enter incident name: ")).upper().rstrip()
//For this example, user inputs 'crash'.

rtcIncidentNameList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rtcincident")

for i in range (0, rtcIncidentNameList.length):
    if rtcIncidentNameList[i].firstChild.data == incidentNameInput:
        print("found incident")
```

However, that final print is never called, as the if statement condition is never met.

Answer (score 1):

No, the child nodes of an element node can be several types: Comment, CDATASection, Text, Element, ProcessingInstruction. An element node can have any count and combination of child nodes.

According to the DOM Standard `data` is implemented in the CharacterData superclass. Text, CDATASection and ProcessingInstruction extend that class.

Comment: I’ve edited the question to show the context of the problem. Could you please explain your answer in relation to that?

Answer (score 1):

No, here's an example:

```
<span><span></span> trailing text</span>
```

The outer `span` has a `firstChild` which is an element, not a text node: the inner `span`. For its part, the inner `span` has `firstChild === null`.

If you are using a DOM 3 implementation and you want the textual content of a node *and* of all its children, you can use the `textContent` property. See this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) for details and a browser support chart. If you are using a DOM 2 or lower implementation, you are going to have to compute it yourself by walking the nodes.

Comment: `Node.textContent` is a DOM 3 feature. Python documentation says it implements DOM 2 only.

Comment: True. I've edited. I did not put much weight in the fact that the OP is using Python. I use Python every day and yet benefit from the latest DOM features because I use Python to control a browser (for testing) rather than depend on whatever DOM implementation is bundled with the Python distribution.